# Graphical glitches

Tags: graphics-card, street-fighter-iv

I have graphical glitches when I play Street Fighter IV on PC.

Sometimes when I play, the 3D models are like leaking to or from nowhere. An image is worth a thousand words, isn't it. Please visit that [IS gallery](http://imageshack.us/g/683/20110721221754programma.png/).

I'm wondering why this happens. Look under Sakura's skirt, on Chun Li's cheek or Dan's hand. It happens randomly.

Obviously I didn't have the problem in the beginning and then it happened but deeper than what you can see on the screenshots, then I changed my monitor because the previous died and it even happened on char select and vs screen (greenish and magenta dotted lines on 2D graphics) but now it seems it got better. I had to play over an hour to get these screens.

I preferred to play on windowed mode and now I play in full-screen mode.

My previous screen was displaying at 1280×1024 as far as I remember and the new one displays HD (1920×1080) so I bet it had to display Windows desktop AND the game graphics and the change of definition may have made some extra work to the GC. Maybe full-screen mode allows it to ease the GPU a bit.

Another thing that happens is the game quitting suddenly.

As I told earlier, my pc is quite old (it actually passes the minimum required config)
Athlon 64 3800+
1 GB of RAM
ATI Radeon x1600 Pro
Windows Seven x64

**In short** : why do these glitches happen and what are the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes even if it passed the minimum required configuration, you won't have a perfect gameplay. Some glitches like this may occur because of the small amount of RAM left to play the game and the graphic card can't handle it at all. Running Win7 on 1Gb of RAM .... seriously, you should consider putting more RAM since Win7 already needs that 1Gb of RAM to run in the background.

Win7 on 64 bit needs at least 2Gb of RAM minimum, so I think you should upgrade

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/system-requirements

Comment: Thank you for your precious answer. I know my PC is quite old (I told it) but if I have such a low config it is cimply because I have no way to have anything better. Actually I'm now jobless and I cannot consider upgrading my machine for the moment. (And if I get a job I will build a brand new PC ^^). Anyway thank you for the information you have provided. I won't care much about this for the moment.

Comment: No problem, could you please green check my answer so I can get a little reward for my precious service :D

Comment: Vote up needs 15 reputation. T_T Sorry for I can't vote up for the moment but thank you anyway.

Comment: Not the vote, the check under the vote, it can be clicked to tell that is was your answer.